# Using Main to Manage Dice

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a simple program that reads two dice input after they are rolled 100000 times and stores them as a histogram. However, I did everything utilizing one class file. My instructor wanted me to use Main to manage the Dice, but I have only finished the dice but don't know how to integrate it to main.

The program I wrote:

```
public class Histogram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] frequency = new int [13];
    int die1, die2;
    int rolls;
    int asterisk;
    int total;
    double probability;

    rolls = 100000;

    //Roll the dice
    for (int i=0; i<rolls; i++) {
         die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
         die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
         total = die1 + die2;  
            frequency[total]++;    
    }

    System.out.println("Results" + '\n' + "Each " + '\"' + "*" + '\"' + " represents the probability in one percent.");
    System.out.println("The total number of rolls is one hundred thousand.");
    System.out.println("Value\tFrequency\tProbability");

    for (total=2; total<frequency.length; total++){ 
        System.out.print(total + ": \t"+frequency[total]+"\t\t");
        probability = (float) frequency[total] / rolls;
        asterisk = (int) Math.round(probability * 100);

        for (int i=0; i<asterisk; i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

The dice:

```
public class Dice {

private int die1;
private int die2;

public Dice() {

    roll();
    }
public void roll() {

    die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    }

public int getDie1() {
    return die1;
    }
public int getDie2() {
    return die2;
    }
public int getTotal() {
    return die1 + die2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
//Roll the dice
for (int i=0; i<rolls; i++) {
     die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
     die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
     total = die1 + die2;  
        frequency[total]++;    
}
```

With this:

```
Dice d = new Dice();
for (int i = 0; i < rolls; i++) {
    d.roll();
    frequency[d.getTotal()]++;
}
```

I don't know how great your implementation of a pair of dice is, though.  I think you could roll anywhere from a 1 to a 7.  Also I'm not sure what the "Bravo()" function is supposed to be, you can probably remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to something like this:

```
//Roll the dice
Dice myDice = new Dice();
for (int i=0; i<rolls; i++) {
    myDice.Bravo();
    die1 = myDice.getDie1();
    die2 = myDice.getDie2();
    total = myDice.getTotal();  
    frequency[total]++;    
}
```